# How to configure Jenkins for distributed load using multiple Jmeter-servers

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I use Jmeter to generate a huge load to my web-server. Some slave machines are acted as Jmeter-server, another one - as Jmeter master that coordinates the load and collects statistics from slaves. 
Now I'm trying to integrate this system to CI (Jenkins). 
That's how I do it now. I have two separate Jenkins jobs: one of them prepares all slaves by running jmeter-server, another one runs Jmeter-master itself. All is fine with 2nd part: I successfully generate traffic and collect statistics. The issue is with 1st job. I have a huge set of slaves that can be rebooted anytime. So, I can't run the job that initiates jmeter-server once and forget about it. I need to run this job every time before Jmeter-master. 
But in this case on some machines (that were not rebooted) I have multiple copies of java processes (jmeter-server copies). 
So, I'm looking for a mechanism to start jmeter-server on slave nodes in a proper way.
Any ideas appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I know how to check the list of processes running on slave machines and how to kill some of them. So, as an idea I tried to kill all java processes before jmeter-server start. But it also kills Jenkins-slave java process. If you know how to identify java processes related to jmeter-server only - it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

- https://dzone.com/articles/distributed-performance

It combines:

- JMeter
- Maven Lazery JMeter plugin
- Jenkins

All you have to do for jmeter-slaves is to start them from Jenkins using jmeter-server.sh , you might want to tweak port if you have 2 slaves on same host.

Then from controller you will reference those host machines (in this casse default port is used):

> remote_hosts=test-server-1.nerdability.com,test-server-2.nerdability.com,test-server-3.nerdability.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Already found this topic before as I browsed the whole internet for many hours before disturbing smart but very busy specialists on stackoverflow :) So, the link describes how to run tests, and, as I wrote, I know how to do that. What I'm really looking for is the way to prepare (using Jenkins) slave nodes to be able to receive commands from Jmeter-master. Anyway, thanks again for spending time trying to help me. Appreciated.

Comment: Yep, and it really works. But I have ~ 50 slave machines. Moreover, slave nodes can be rebooted. So, I can't run jmeter-server once and forget about it. I'm looking for a mechanism to start jmeter-server on every node from slave list before Jmeter-master start. Currently I perform it using a separate Jenkins job that just executes a simple command line string on each slave, but it's not the best solution, because on some boxes (that were not rebooted) I have two java instances (two jmeter-server) running.

Comment: I also wrote a simple script that deletes all java.exe processes before starting jmeter-server, but it was a bad idea as it also terminates jenkins-slave processes too :) If you know a way how I can identify which of java processes running on the box belong to jmeter-server, then I can easily kill these processes over script, and it can solve my problem.