# How do we configure Jenkins to usea particular instance/machine as a JMeter Master instance

Tags: jmeter

I tried solutions listed on Stackoverflow i.e.:

[How to configure Jenkins for distributed load using multiple Jmeter-servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401126/how-to-configure-jenkins-for-distributed-load-using-multiple-jmeter-servers)

However when I trigger a job from Jenkins, it looks for JMeter-server Master install in local machine.

Question:
1. How to configure Jenkins to look for Jemeter-server Master instance running on a specific machine
2. can I run my jmeter-server master instance on a separate machine than where Jenkins is running.
3. How Jenkins identify which instance is Master and which instance is slave

Answer (score 0):

You need to familiarise yourself with the concept of [Jenkins Distributed Builds](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) feature.

1. On Jenkins Master open "Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes"

   [image: Jenkins Manage Nodes]
2. Click "New Node" and provide a meaningful name for it (I use "Windows" since my master is running on a Mac and I'm going to have a Windows slave)
3. Perform the necessary configuration (here I use `Launch agent via Java Web Start` option ) and save it.

   [image: Jenksns slave configuration]
4. On the machine which you are going to use as a slave open the same page ("Manage Jenkins -> "Manage Nodes"). You will see a new node called "Windows"

   [image: Jenkins Windows Slave]
5. Use one of the provided ways to launch a Jenkins slave on the agent

   [image: Jenkins launch agent]
6. Assuming everything goes well you should be able to see a new "Windows" slave machine

   [image: Jenkins New Slave]

   7. So now you should be able to "tell" Jenkins where you would like the build to be executed via `Restrict where this project can be run` setting:

   [image]

References:

- [Step by step guide to set up master and slave machines on Windows](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows)
- [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins)